# Using HINT and TRACE with GemfireTemplate.query method

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, oql

I am trying to add a Trace to an OQL Query as mentioned in the [docs](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/geode/developing/query_additional/query_debugging.html), using GemfireTemplate [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-). But the OQL validation fails with QueryInvalidException "unexpected tokern: <". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why the exception is being thrown, apparently the query generated by the `GemFireTemplate` is somehow invalid?. Anyways, I've been able to workaround the problem by using `GemFireTemplate.find("<TRACE> SELECT * FROM /myRegion)` instead of `GemFireTemplate.query("<TRACE> SELECT * FROM /myRegion)`.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to use [Spring Data for Apache Geode Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories) and the [@Trace](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories.queries.oql-extensions) instead of the `GemFireTemplate`, is more straightforward and allows you to significantly reduce the amount of boilerplate code required to implement data access layers.

Comment: @juan - Why do you think the query generated by `GemfireTemplate` when calling the `GemfireTemplate.query(:String)` method is invalid?  First of all, it doesn't "generate" any query... it passes the argument to the `query(:String)` method directly to the GemFire/Geode API.  See my answer below.

Comment: Hey @John, I didn't investigate that much into the stack trace and "invalid" was not the right word to use, sorry about that; I just saw on the logs from the server that the `queryString` didn't look right. After reading your answer, though, it's clear where the problem is; and I didn't know about the `Region.query()` method restriction, BTW, thanks for pointing that out!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug with SDG's `GemfireTemplate`, nor a problem with SDG in general.

There are 2 ways to query in GemFire/Geode.

1. First, is to use the [`QueryService`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/query/QueryService.html), which can be obtained [from the cache](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionService.html#getQueryService--). Alternatively, you can obtai the `QueryService` [from the `ClientCache`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientCache.html#getLocalQueryService--) or even [from the `Pool`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/client/Pool.html#getQueryService--) attached to the `Region` on which you are running the OQL query. This is all handled for you automatically when using SDG's [Repository abstraction extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories).
2. The second way to query a `Region` is to pass a query "PREDICATE" to the [`Region.query(:String)`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#query-java.lang.String-) method.

Which GemFire/Geode API do you think the `GemfireTemplate.query(:String)` method is using?

`GemfireTemplate.query(:String)` [uses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.4.0-M2/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java#L281) the `Region.query(:String)` API.

The `GemfireTemplate.find(:String)` method [uses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.4.0-M2/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java#L312-L323) the `QueryService`.

Only the `QueryService` can accept fully valid OQL queries, e.g. `<TRACE> SELECT * FROM /SomeRegion WHERE id = 1`, where as the `Region.query(:String)` method ONLY accepts the OQL Query PREDICATE, i.e. `id = 1`.

Any other [OQL Query reserved words](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/112/developing/query_additional/supported_keywords.html) or [query syntax](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/112/developing/query_additional/query_language_features.html) in general, passed to the `GemfireTemplate.query(:String)` method (and by extension `Region.query(:String)` API) results in a invalid OQL Query.

If you want to pass `<HINT 'IDIndex', ...> <TRACE> SELECT * FROM /SomeRegion WHERE id = 1 AND ...`, then you should call `GemfireTemplate.find(:String)`, which uses the GemFire/Geode `QueryService` that accepts the complete OQL Query syntax.

Alternatively, you can use the *Spring Data for Apache Geode* (or VMware Tanzu GemFire) *Repository* extension.

It is even still possible to add HINTS, TRACES, LIMITS or other query facilities to derived Repository query methods as well as query methods annotated with `@Query`.  See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories.queries.oql-extensions) for more details.